# how to stucture relational data from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to writing apps and I have created an app that I need country city state data for each user so that they can let people know where they are living.

I have been searching for datasets that contain that data and how to use it.

All the data I can find is relationally structured so the cities have ids for state and country

I know it would be possible to write queries to gather this data into some format to allow them to select the country state/provice and city they are living in (although I need to find out how) but I was wondering if there is a better way to store the data so that I do not have to jump through hoops to get at the data. I was hoping to use the Easy Search package for Meteor to accomplish this.

The current data set I am working off is from Geobytes GeoWorldMap http://www.geobytes.com/GeoWorldMap.zip

The dataset examples look like this

```
Countries
"CountryId","Country","FIPS104","ISO2","ISO3","ISON","Internet","Capital","MapReference","NationalitySingular","NationalityPlural","Currency","CurrencyCode","Population","Title","Comment"
1,"Afghanistan","AF","AF","AFG","4","AF","Kabul ","Asia ","Afghan","Afghans","Afghani ","AFA",26813057,"Afghanistan",""
2,"Albania","AL","AL","ALB","8","AL","Tirana ","Europe ","Albanian","Albanians","Lek ","ALL",3510484,"Albania",""

State (Region File)

"RegionId","CountryId","Region","Code","ADM1Code"
1,14,"Victoria","VI","AS07"
2,14,"Tasmania","TS","AS06"
3,14,"Queensland","QL","AS04"
4,14,"New South Wales","NS","AS02"

City

"CityId","CountryID","RegionID","City","Latitude","Longitude","TimeZone","DmaId","Code"
42231,1,833,"Herat","34.333","62.2","+04:30",0,"HERA"
5976,1,835,"Kabul","34.517","69.183","+04:50",0,"KABU"
42230,1,852,"Mazar-e Sharif","36.7","67.1","+4:30",0,"MSHA"
42412,2,983,"Korce","40.6162","20.7779","+01:00",0,"KORC"
5977,2,1011,"Tirane","41.333","19.833","+01:00",0,"TIRA"
```

I have imported the data into three separate collections but I am not sure that will be the best way forward. As the city dataset is quite large I want to be able to filter on country then state/province and finally just the cities there.

Any suggestions on how I should go about this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to be careful about if you plan for this app to be used on mobile or on a slow connection:
1) Be careful about what you include in your subscriptions. You do not want or need this whole data set on the client. You probably don't want to subscribe to this data at all.
2) You mentioned filtering. Meteor (and MongoDB for that matter) do not automatically add indexes. So if you know that you will be filtering cities by CountryID or RegionID then you will need to setup the indexes yourself.

I think that you are taking the best approach for representing the data in Mongo/Meteor. You definitely do not want to have a single collection called "Locations" that has Countries with a Regions sublist which has "Cities" sublists.

However, is there any reason that you need to host this yourself? Sounds like a nightmare to maintain since new cities and regions are added fairly often. Could you use a 3rd party service? This would allow you to call directly from the client or do server side caching. Then you could allow the service to handle the filtering functionality/complexity. This is the first approach that I would look into and fall back to hosting it myself if there was not a cost effective solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. At the moment I do not have budget to use a pay for hosted service. Unless you know of a way I could get this information into my application? I was hoping to use this in a mobile app as well so you comments on indexes are very pertinent.

Comment: I have not used this in any products, but it looks like you can use < 100,000 requests to google's place's autocomplete API each day for free. See: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete